# Reclarification of how feof() of php work

Tags: php, feof

I have read [the comment about `feof()` on PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php#67261), [the answer here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32644390/9060223) and [another answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5605159/9060223).

So I've understood that using `feof()` does not mean using a 'crystal ball' to magically know whether there are more characters or lines in a stream, as mentioned second link above. Rather, **it is a test that indicates whether an input operation failed or not** (in this case, I only care about the input operation of `fgetc()` of PHP). So the last character read will still be okay. **AND THEN**, the `feof()` of `while(!feof($file_you_read_from))` will still be **false** simply because the last `fgetc()` still succeeded and **after** one more loop where `fgetc()` attempts to read and fail, only then will `feof()` be set to **true**. Am I correct? Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`feof` in PHP works the same as C.

If it is `false` then it checks the last operation otherwise returns the cached value.

[Source is here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.4/main/streams/streams.c#L727)

[Comment for C's `feof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/feof/)

> Checks whether the end-of-File indicator associated with stream is
>   set, returning a value different from zero if it is.
>
> This indicator is generally set by a previous operation on the stream
>   that attempted to read at or past the end-of-file.
>
> Notice that stream's internal position indicator may point to the
>   end-of-file for the next operation, but still, the end-of-file
>   indicator may not be set until an operation attempts to read at that
>   point.
>
> This indicator is cleared by a call to clearerr, rewind, fseek,
>   fsetpos or freopen. Although if the position indicator is not
>   repositioned by such a call, the next i/o operation is likely to set
>   the indicator again.

Comment: I see. So my assumption is correct: that the value of `feof()` is set by the **latest** operation of read, i.e. the `fgetc()` I mentioned, right?

Comment: A bit wrong, it affects by the latest opertion but set by `feof`, you can check the source code.

Comment: Do you mean this one: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.4/main/streams/streams.c#L727? Admittedly, I have some trouble understanding that section.

Comment: So that means, it is set by `feof()`, and `feof()` knows which value to set by getting the status of the last operation of read, right?